# Ansible for user management -removing dead accounts

Tags: ansible, user-management

How to efficiently manage user accounts in Ansible?
I want to keep user accounts and certificates in list.

When running playbook I would like to create every account from list (thats easy).
I also want to remove accounts existing on host, but not present in list.

For now, I figured out list existing accounts 
`awk -F: '($3 >= 1000) {printf "%s\n",$1}' /etc/passwd`

and compare it with my list- removing unwanted accounts.

Is there easier way- module that does that out-of-the-box?

Comment: I have one thought: use your snippet in a local fact (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d) so that the users on each server can be accessed as an array from the playbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**WARNING** **CAUTION** Do it only if you are absolutely sure about the user to be removed. This may make your system useless if you remove system users like **root**.

Few lines of Ansible can do what you are asking for. Leverage the `user` module.

```
  vars:
    myusers: ['root', 'bin', 'mail', 'obama', 'trump', 'clinton', 'you', 'me']

  tasks:
  - shell: 'cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd'
    register: users
  - user: name={{item}} state=absent remove=yes
    with_items: users.stdout_lines
    when: item not in myusers
```

Comment: You need to be really careful about doing things this way. You would need to specify all of the system users or it will remove them.

Comment: @smiller171 you are correct. If not used correctly, it will render the machine useless.

Comment: The solution I use has you specify users to remove, rather than deleting everything not in a list.

Comment: Also just suggested an edit so that your example doesn't mark anything as changed unless it has changed something.

Comment: With more recent versions of Ansible you'd use `loop`. Having said that, this code will fail with `'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines' if no items exist (e.g. if you try extending this code to groups).

Answer (score 8):

Search for user-id > 1000 when parsing `/etc/passwd` and add `nobody` to the list of valid users. This way you're not removing any system users.

```
vars:
  myusers: ['nobody', 'obama', 'trump', 'clinton', 'you', 'me']

tasks:
- shell: "getent passwd | awk -F: '$3 > 1000 {print $1}'"
  register: users

- user: name={{item}} state=absent remove=yes
  with_items: users.stdout_lines
  when: item not in myusers
```

Remember to add `nobody` to your list of valid users.

Comment: Unfortunately, `getent passwd` does not list remote users, e.g. coming from `sssd`.

Comment: Well, you won't get coffee out of a tea maker.

Comment: On Centos 7 with NFS instead of `nobody` you will have `nfsnobody` user.

Comment: Why do you want remote users to be listed here, @yktoo? I think that you should remove them in their source, like LDAP, in a source-specific way.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this Ansible role I wrote: https://galaxy.ansible.com/smiller171/manage_users

Comment: URL leads to 404.

Comment: Looks like my username ended up changing, breaking the URL I've edited my answer